# How would I mock the axios call in my controller in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

So my axios call is an already separated module and tested via mocking axios itself. However, when I import this function into my controller, what is the best way to test the controller itself? I know it needs to be mocked, but I am unsure of the most efficient way of mocking it so I can test the req and res (which are also mocked).

The axios call is **getAddressWithPostcode**

**Controller**:

```
const findAddress = async (req: Request<Params>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { params } = req

  await getAddressWithPostcode(params)
    .then((data) => {
      if (!isUndefined(data.status)) {
        return res.status(data.status).send(data.data.Message)
      }

      return res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      next(err)
    })
}
```

**Axios call:**

```
const getAddressWithPostcode = async (params: Params) => {
  const { postCode, number } = params

  const addressUrl = `${process.env.URL}/${postCode}${number
    ? `/${number}?api-key=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    : `?api-key=${process.env.API_KEY}`}`

  try {

    const { data } = await axios.get(addressUrl)
    return data

  } catch (e) {

    const { response } = e
    return response

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // users.test.js
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from './users';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should fetch users', () => {
  const users = [{name: 'Bob'}];
  const resp = {data: users};
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  // or you could use the following depending on your use case:
  // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp))

  return Users.all().then(data => expect(data).toEqual(users));
});
```

This example uses jest to test an axios call, same can be extended to any library. Hope it gets you started

can find more details on unit testing with jest  [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-return-values)

Comment: I understand the need to mock the resolved value, what I would like to do is to test the status and data of the resp object in the controller, alongside the axios call

Comment: if you have already mocked the axios , just write a unit test , do axios.post('yourendpoint').then((res)=>{
expect(res).tobe(your mockresponse)}) fairly simple